# Explicitly state type for nullable field with a JSONObject

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I am working with the Json Simple library, but I need a variable to explicitly say what type of variable this is. For example,

```
"date": {"int": 18002},
```

Otherwise it will not be able to be posted to the kafka server. Right now I am using this code:

```java
jsonFileObject.put("date", Integer.parseInt(expectedDate));
```

which always just comes out as

```
"date":18002
```

Is there anyway to ensure it comes out the first way?

Comment: Instead of putting an `int`, explicitly put a `JSONObject` with the structure you require.

Comment: How would i mark that JSONObject as an int structure?

Comment: Just add a field called int to it with the value you want.

Comment: Awesome, that worked, thank you so much!